# Configurations needed to be done post GCC compilation and installation

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, gcc

I have compiled the latest GCC 4.7.0, on my Linux Mint 12, using gcc 4.6.1 (default).

Compiler compiled successfully, steps followed

1. ./configure
2. make
3. make install

Binaries of gcc-4.7.0 are in /usr/local/bin/ after install step.

Now the goal is to make the new compiler the default while also keeping the old one around(no uninstall) i.e. I want to be able to do gcc a.c or g++ a.cpp directly in the terminal window.

 I have been unable to find a proper series of steps that would help me accomplish this.

 Also, doing /usr/local/bin/g++ hello-world.cpp generates iostream file/directory not found.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Copy-paste the exact commands you ran and the exact error messages.

Comment: @Gilles: The exact commands :
1) ./configure
2)make
3)make install
Put /usr/local/bin in PATH in .bashrc. 
Now I run g++ -v and I get version 4.7.0 but gcc -v gets version 4.6.1 and also following are the contents

apt
c++
cpp
g++
gcc    -- directory that contains xgcc(binary)
gcc-ar
gcc-nm
gcc-ranlib
gcov
highlight
i686-pc-linux-gnu-c++
i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++
i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
mint-md5sum
search

/usr/local/bin/g++ a.cpp , generates the error message that iostream file/directory not found, compilation aborted.

Comment: Edit your question, please, with formatting (check the preview below the edit box to see if it looks readable). In a comment, with no newlines, this is very hard to read.

Comment: The exact commands : 
 1. ./configure 
 2. make 
 3. make install 
 4. Put /usr/local/bin in PATH in .bashrc.
 5. Now I run g++ -v and I get version 4.7.0 but gcc -v gets version 4.6.1. 
/usr/local/bin/  contents
  1. apt
  2. c++
  3. cpp
  4. g++
  5. gcc -- directory xgcc(binary)
  6. gcc-ar gcc-nm 
  7. gcc-ranlib 
  8. gcov 
  9. highlight
  10. i686-pc-linux-gnu-c++ 
  11. i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++ 
  12. i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ar 
  13. i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-nm   
  14. i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib 
  15. mint-md5sum search

Comment: Really embarrassed and sorry, I tried using <ol>,</ol>,<br> and what not but I don't seem to be getting it right.

Comment: You can't use (much) formatting in a comment. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Mint is from Debian family, so likely gcc is installed in separate packages and /usr/bin/gcc is only symlink. Even if you don't package gcc-4.7 properly you can install it into designated path (e.g. /opt/gcc47) and then change symlink set (gcc, cpp, g++) to point to your installed version.

Don't install gcc-4.7 into standard paths like /usr/local/bin without reversing symlinks in /usr/bin. Some tools can drop PATH or rewrite it so result will be unpredictable.

You can add option -v to gcc command line to ask printing of commands and searching process to detect which binaries are really called and what is incorrect.